# How can I get Alexa rank from client side (jQuery)?

Tags: jquery, json, rank, alexa-internet

I need to read Alexa rank from client side with usage of jQuery.
The URL is like this:

```
http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&data=snbamz&url=http://www.facebook.com
```

The returned object is XML formatted so I cannot use JSON. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

The following link gives step by step instructions on how to read the data and display it.

http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/

You basically have to dig into each level, which will need to be made custom to your application and the data being pulled.

### Addition

In order to pull the xml data from an external domain, first pull it into a separate page on your site using php.  Once the data is in a local page you may do whatever you want with it.

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&data=snbamz&url=http://www.facebook.com');
echo $homepage;
```

Comment: they use ajax method and it doesn't seems to work cross domain :(

Comment: Are you working with PHP?  You can pull an XML resource into a PHP page hosted on your domain and make the XML file available from that page.